# Can I change the window lock screen "reset password" application?

Tags: windows-7, windows, passwords, password-recovery, lock-screen

If you use Forefront Identity Manager (FIM) Self Service Password Reset, there is a reset password link on your windows 7 lock screen that opens the FIM password reset application:

[image: lockscreen with fim password reset]

Is it possible to edit this link, so that it opens a self developed application?

Comment: Yes, and for the love of bacon clean your monitor man!

Comment: Its not the monitor, its my phone camera that sucks :/ Did not manage to do print screen when the computer was locked. And if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

It is also not incredibly easy to get to work reliably. This is partially by design, because by altering the Windows Logon process you could also lower or bypass security.

In short:

**Windows 2000/ NT/ XP**
Replace [MSGINA.DLL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_identification_and_authentication) in the registry with a custom DLL and update the registry.

**Windows NT 6.0+ (Vista+)**
[You need to create a custom Credential Provider.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx)

---

If you research this further you will see there are many examples and tutorials. Neither route is exceptionally easy.